# If i have a page with different css styles and i want to load it onto a page that has it's own css styles inside of an iframe

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to change the css in that iframe upon loading through jquery?

This is what I got:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("div#skiptrace div.global-header").css('display', 'none');
            });
    </script>
   <div id="skiptrace"><iframe name="my_iframe" src="" id="skiptrace"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to change div.global-header to display:none.. I have several other div's that i would not want to load by simply hiding with css.

Comment: Are pages on the same domain? As "don't want to load" you mean "not show" or something else (i.e. really force page not to load this tags)?

Comment: The page is on a different domain and I'm pulling the styles from the other page as well. I want to hide most all of the styling except the styling for one or two div classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate ID's, this assumes your iFrame ID is skiptrace.

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#skiptrace").load( function() {
        $(this).contents().find("div.global-header").css('display', 'none');
    });
});
</script>

<div id="skiptraceContainer">
    <iframe name="my_iframe" src="" id="skiptrace"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the IFrame's content().find(selector).  First you would need to fix your id's on the div and the iframe, assume the iframe's id is iskiptrace.

```
<div id="skiptrace">
    <iframe name="my_iframe" src="" id="iskiptrace"></iframe>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadPage(url)
    {
        $("#iskiptrace").attr('src', url);
        $("#iskiptrace").load( function()
        {
            $("#iskiptrace").content().find(".hidable").css('display', 'none');
        });
    }

    loadPage("iframeIndex.html");
</script>
```